# Access Facebook page wall post (Questions and Poll options)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I was wondering if there is a way to access Questions / Polls and Answers that have been published on my facebook page.

Plus, I would like to post new Questions / Polls from my website. Is that feasible.

Facebook Questions ?

> Use Questions to get recommendations, conduct polls and learn from
>   your fans and other people on Facebook.

Thanks in advance.

Jk_

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick run through the plugin directory and I don't see anything that currently handles this.

It would be possible if someone either integrated with the API or if someone did something like an iFrame to the poll itself.

Comment: I did search too into the API but I didn't find anything about that ! I keep searching tough.